# import another py file with option

Tags: python, module

I have `main.py` and `newcanmonitor.py` I want to import `newcanmonitor.py` with `vcan0` option because when I use `newcanmonitor.py` alone I type in `python newcanmonitor.py vcan0` in the terminal

**main.py**

```
import newcanmonitor ???  <-- is there any way to use an option 'vcan0' here?
```

**newcanmonitor.py**

```
def read_bus(bus_device):
    """Read data from `bus_device` until the next newline character."""
    message = bus.recv(0.2)
    while True:
        if message:
            break
        message = bus.recv(0.2)

    try:
        string = "{}:ID={}:LEN={}".format("RX", message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)
        for x in range(message.dlc):
            string += ":{:02x}".format(message.data[x])

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return string
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: you can't import with options. You should keep code in functions and after importing code you should run this function with your option

Comment: or you can try to uses `sys.argv.append("vcan0")` before you import module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to uses `sys.argv.append("vcan0")` before you import module.

```
import sys

sys.argv.append("vcan0")
import newcanmonitor
```

but I don't know if will work with module because module will import `sys` and it can get fresh `sys.argv` without `"vcan0"`

---

But I would rather use `if __name__ == "__main__"` to run code in differene way when it is executed directly and in different way when it is imported.

This way standalone version could get value from `sys.argv` and send to function - `read_bus(sys.argv)` - and `main.py` can import function and run directly `read_bus("vcan0")`

**newcanmonitor.py**

```
def read_bus(bus_device):
    """Read data from `bus_device` until the next newline character."""
    message = bus.recv(0.2)
    while True:
        if message:
            break
        message = bus.recv(0.2)

    try:
        string = "{}:ID={}:LEN={}".format("RX", message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)
        for x in range(message.dlc):
            string += ":{:02x}".format(message.data[x])

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    read_bus(sys.argv[1])
```

**main.py**

```
import newcanmonitor

newcanmonitor.read_bus("vcan0")
```